# Django form with two models

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

Now i want create form in which I could edit both models ( I want display cart with products and have possibility to edit price of every product from this cart). I used inlineformset_factory but it displays error. I use this way first time so I have no idea what must I change.

> 'shop.Product' has no ForeignKey to 'shop.Cart'.

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField(default='0')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{}({})".format(self.name, self.price)

class Cart(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class CartForm(forms.ModelForm):
    product = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = Product.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),required=True) 
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=45, label='nazwa')
    price = forms.IntegerField(label='price')

    class Meta: 
        model = Cart
        fields = ('product', 'name', 'price')

IngredientFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Cart, Product)
```

views.py

```
def cart_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CartForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cart = form.save(commit=False)
            cart.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            ingredient_formset = IngredientFormSet(request.POST)
            if ingredient_formset.is_valid():
                ingredient = formset.save(commit=False)
                ingredient_formset.save()
                return redirect('shop.views.cart_detail', pk=cart.pk)
    else:
        form = CartForm()
    return render(request, 'shop/cart_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

error:

```
    Traceback:
File "C:\Users\znawca\myapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  119.                 resolver_product = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "C:\Users\znawca\myapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  366.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Users\znawca\myapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  402.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Users\znawca\myapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  396.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "D:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "C:\Users\znawca\myapp\league\league\urls.py" in <module>
  6.     url(r'', include('shop.urls')),
File "C:\Users\znawca\myapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py" in include
  33.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "D:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "C:\Users\znawca\myapp\league\shop\urls.py" in <module>
  2. from . import views
File "C:\Users\znawca\myapp\league\shop\views.py" in <module>
  2. from .forms import *
File "C:\Users\znawca\myapp\league\shop\forms.py" in <module>
  19. IngredientFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Cart, Product)
File "C:\Users\znawca\myapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in inlineformset_factory
  1020.     fk = _get_foreign_key(parent_model, model, fk_name=fk_name)
File "C:\Users\znawca\myapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in _get_foreign_key
  992.                     parent_model._meta.object_name,

Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: 'shop.Product' has no ForeignKey to 'shop.Cart'.
```

Comment: Please post your view method and your full error stack trace please.

Comment: Hi @Shang Wang I edited first post. I don't know it is all what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As you can find in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet), inline formsets are only usable for foreign keys, not for M2M fields. You will have to build your own formset manually.

You would go about it like this:

```
# In your view:
IngredientFormSet = modelformset_factory(Product)
ingredient_formset = IngredientFormSet(
    request.POST, request.FILES,
    queryset=cart.product.all()
)
```

You will also want to tweak the actual saving to attach the ingredients to their cart.

```
# cart has already been saved
ingredients = ingredient_formset.save()
cart.product = ingredients
```

Comment: Thank you, this view looks good but what must I change in forms.py to make it correct?